# How to select a SQLConnection from SQLConnections[] by its "Name" property?

Tags: databaselink

When creating a `SQLConnection` you can give it a name with the `"Name"` option. The connections are also added to the output of the `SQLConnections` function.

```
OpenSQLConnection[ 
  JDBC["HSQL(Standalone)", ToFileName[{$TemporaryDirectory, "SE Question"}, "Ex1"] ], 
   "Name" -> "Example1"];
OpenSQLConnection[ 
  JDBC["HSQL(Standalone)", ToFileName[{$TemporaryDirectory, "SE Question"}, "Ex2"] ], 
    "Name" -> "Example2"];
SQLConnections[]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Later on I would like to select a particular connection from `SQLConnections` based on its name.  However, `SQLConnectionInformation` does not have `"Name"` as supported property

```
SQLConnectionInformation[#, "Name"] & /@ SQLConnections[]
```

> DatabaseLink`JDBC::error
>
> ```
> {$Failed, $Failed}
> ```

and there does not seem to be a name property on the connections

```
Through@SQLConnections[]["Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and `SQLConnections` does not take a name parameter

```
SQLConnections["Example1"]
```

> ```
> SQLConnections["Example1"]
> ```

How do I select a connection from `SQLConnections` by its `"Name"` property?

*Clean-up:*

```
CloseSQLConnection /@ SQLConnections[];
```

---

#### Update

WRI Support have provided a method to get at the "Name".  I have also requested that a `SQLConnection` object support `"Name"` and `"Id"` as properties.

`"Name"` is an option.  Therefore,

```
"Name" /. Options[conn, "Name"]
```

will provide `conn`'s `"Name"` option.

For the `"Id"` property WRI said it is the third part of its FullForm.  Therefore,

```
conn[[3]]
```

will provide `conn`'s `"Id"` property.  This method seems particularly risky since there is no guarantee that this position will contain this property in future versions.

Since you can see these values in the `Format` form of a SQLConnection in a notebook I think it is reasonable to expect to be able to get at these values without workarounds. Particularly since there is no other means of selecting a connection out of the `SQLConnections` list.  Fingers are optimistically crossed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Name` option is not unique, so we could be more than one result, if we ask all connections with a particular name.  Try this:

```
connName = "Example2";
Select[SQLConnections[],
 StringMatchQ["Name" /. Cases[Flatten[List @@ #], _Rule],
   connName] &
 ]
```

The `Select` should give us all of connections with name "Example2".

How it works:  We take a single connection and replace the head with `List`, then `Flatten` the list.  We are interested only in the Rules associated with connection.  We apply all of the replacement rules to "Name", which gives us the string name of the connection, assuming there is one.  If that string matches the one we want, we select the connection.

Comment: Nice work. I didn't think to deconstruct the connection. +1 while we wait for  other solutions.